# Google voice auto reply script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to auto reply to google voice texts during non business hours? I am looking to have a script that replies to the user they are outside of normal business hours if it is not between 9 and 5 EST mon- fri, or 9-12 Sat. Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

As per [program policies](https://www.google.com/googlevoice/program-policies.html), no.

> - sending messages via an automated process, such as a script;